# using of iframes inside the onclick event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I am using kendoUI.
I have three views in my splitter in left-pane,center-pane and right-pane.
I have loaded left-pane and center-pane views inside the splitter using iframes and third view is empty.

The view which is in my center-pane contains a button "details",when i click on this button the corresponding details has to display on the view page which is in the right-pane.

Any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ajaxRequest](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/splitter#ajaxrequest) method provided by the Splitter API to say that the #rightpane should be loaded from some URL you pass and also you can pass additional data if you need to.
Give a try, it is really convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the response,Initially the view in the right-pane load with just labels only.after clicking the "details" button from the center-pane can i update the right-pane view The corresponding details.